# 'TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource' on form submit ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to fetch some data from my API with Cross-Origin enabled but got this error.
Same thing with [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) (an online REST API for testing) using an example they provide :

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

Both requests (JSONPlaceholder and my API) work fine using Insomnia (a REST client), so my guess is that the problem is in my React application (16.13.1).

### EDIT

After some tests, it seems that the error only occurs when calling the fetch function from a `<form>`, here are some details :

```
handleSubmit = () => {
   fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
}
```

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
    <button type="submit">FETCH</button>
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: could you provide the full error you got? Or was it just the "TypeError: NetworkError"?

Comment: Yes that's all, no details.

Comment: You're not catching your error in any way. Try adding .catch(err => console.error(err)) so it prints the full error to the console, and then add the output to your question. It might add some more clarity.

Comment: @Phoenix1355, the catch returns the same message, already tried it.

Comment: have you tried to prevent the default()?  handleSubmit=(e)=>{e.preventDefault() ...etc}

Comment: @DcoderZ, yes that was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed the reproduce your error. It seems like the network request is stopped when the page reloads. You could add a simple `event.preventDefault` to stop the reload until the `fetch` finishes and then reload the page.

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json)
      window.location.reload()
    })
}
```

And of course you can also not reload the page at all for a better user experience :)

Comment: Indeed, the reload was interrupting the request, Thank you!

Comment: @adxl No problem, it's quite easy to miss :)

Comment: @AdamJeliński This worked for me too! Thank you. However, it seems that the form does not get sent now, is there a workaround?

Comment: @pp182 The `event.preventDefault()` specifically prevents the form from submitting, in order to allow the `fetch` to succeed. I think you could replace  `window.location.reload()` (which just reloads the page without submitting) with `event.target.submit()` in order to first make the request and then submit the form.

Comment: @AdamJeliński thanks again! if its not too much trouble would u mind looking at my thread? I havent used window.location.reload() in my code so Im not sure where to place the submit() function.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65382736/html-form-does-not-get-sent-after-onsubmit-function